# ScrollFire plugin seems not to be working

Tags: javascript, materialize

It seems that for some reason `ScrollFire` plugin is not working.

Using [official guide](http://materializecss.com/scrollfire.html) I have created a [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZvyvBuhE0TJXAlx1iebU). Core javascript is the following:

```
Materialize.scrollFire({ selector:".whoosh", offset: 10, callback: "alert('fired')"});
```

It assumes that when scrolling down to image an alert must pop up, but it does not.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the problem is, according to the documentation `options` should be an array. So if you do like this:

```
Materialize.scrollFire([{ selector:".whoosh", offset: 10, callback: "alert('fired')"}]);
```

It should work fine (notice the brackets `[...]`).
In other words:

```
var options = [{ selector:".whoosh", offset: 10, callback: "alert('fired')"}];
Materialize.scrollFire(options);
```

Comment: I have just discovered this by myself by looking at the source code where each passed option was iterated in cycle having length equal to options.length. This why I realized that options object must be an array, and noticed this in documentation also. Thank you, anyway!